# Remove the fading background in a Discourse topic

Tags: css, sass, discourse

I am customizing a theme in a blog based on the Discourse engine. Now each post (or "topic") loads with a blue background, which quickly fades to the main background color. You can see an example [here](https://support.tmatesoft.com/t/multi-module-gradle-configuration-with-git-x-modules/2518).

I was told, that this is caused by [this CSS](https://github.com/discourse/discourse/blob/master/app/assets/stylesheets/common/base/topic-post.scss#L622). So I wrote the following in my custom CSS field:

```
.topic-body .cooked.highlighted {
    animation: none;
}
```

But this has no effect. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. log in as the admin and go to settings
2. Click on customize and then click on your theme
3. Now find the option `Edit CSS/HTML` and click on it
4. In the CSS option add the following code

```css
.highlighted{
     animation:none!important;
}
```

Comment: It worked, thank you! It was `!important` that did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

try taking out this

```
 &.highlighted {
    animation: background-fade-highlight 2.5s ease-out;
  }
```

Comment: I can't modify the original CSS. I need to write custom CSS that overrides it.